# Validation of NotMapped properties in EF Code First + Ria Services

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, wcf-ria-services

I am using RIA Services and EF Code First to create an application where entities are extendable using custom properties (each extendable entity has a property bag which basically is a one to many relation with a Property entity).

Moreover a code generation mechanism has been written that generates 'ordinary' c# property wrappers for each such 'extended' property. Thanks to this the whole mechanism is much more transparent to developers

```
    [NotMapped]
    public string Version
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetProperty(PropertyNameVersionConst) == null
                        ? null
                        : this.GetProperty(PropertyNameVersionConst).StringValue;
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetProperty(PropertyNameVersionConst, value);          
        }
    }
```

The question is - can I use validation attributes on such ([NotMapped]) properties? At first glance I don't see any reason why it shouldn't be possible.

```
[NotMapped]
[Required]
public string Version{...}
```

I've run into an issue where a validation exception (on SaveChanges()) is being thrown for such a property with Required attribute, even though the property HAS been set to a non-null value.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after adding virtual modifier to the properties it started to work properly

```
[NotMapped]
public virtual string Version
{
    get
    {
        return this.GetProperty(PropertyNameVersionConst) == null
                    ? null
                    : this.GetProperty(PropertyNameVersionConst).StringValue;
    }
    set
    {
        this.SetProperty(PropertyNameVersionConst, value);          
    }
}
```

Anyone could elaborate on this :)?

Comment: I have a value-type (struct) property in my model and even though i marked it as `[NotMapped]` EF still validates it's value before saves. i also tried `virtual` modifier but still no chance